# spring boot application with mysql getting "java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException"

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

When I start Spring boot(1.3) application with MySQL (5.7.X), I get the below exception on application startup. Any help would be much appreciated

The driver manages the state of connecting improperly and fails with

> `java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval`

Comment: Can you post your code and classes?

Answer (score 3):

You should add client option  to your mysql-connector `allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true` eg.

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ponto_inteligente?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true`

https://mysql-net.github.io/MySqlConnector/connection-options/

Answer (score 2):

I was able to figure this out, and it was due to the way I configured the user privileges in `mysql`. I was using the authentication method as `SHA256` and when I changed it to `normal`, it started working. Please check this [url](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75670) for more detail.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I was using the following block in application.properties:

```
#MySql
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
*spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ponto_inteligente? 
                         verifyServerCertificate=false&
                         autoReconnect=true&
                         useSSL=false*
spring.datasource.name=USER_LOGIN
spring.datasource.password=USER_PASSWORD

# exibe comandos SQL
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type=trace
```

After changing the second line worked:

```
*spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ponto_inteligente? 
                         verifyServerCertificate=false&
                         autoReconnect=true&
                         useSSL=false&
                         user=USER_LOGIN&
                         password=USER_PASSWORD*
```

Comment: What is the `second line` you changed?